# How to bypass the user confirmation in J2ME?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

i have a j2me application ,
it does the File IO operation, but every time it performs it , it asks user for permission.
is there any way to bypass it?
i heard that suppose if i make this application certified then i would be able to run it in max. secure mode to bypass such issues.

Comment: You might want to read the beginning of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710423/privileged-operations-in-netbeans-mobility/1716755#1716755

Comment: Thanks above for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should acquire a digital certificate from a so-called "certification authority" (such as [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/)) and use the JADTool utility on your jar.

See the [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/docs/refSigning.html) guide.

Comment: then it won't ask for every secured operation ?

Comment: Note that for Java ME, these certificates were fairly expensive.  Systems like Android or, surprisingly, Blackberry, are cheaper to work with.